# What happened to Versioning in Xcode 15?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iOS app with a widget.
Normal housekeeping with updates includes bumping the CFBundleVersion of the app and the Extension to stay in synch.

I just downloaded Xcode15 (release) and while the App Target still have the version and build in the same place in General/Identity, the Extension’s General/ is now missing the Version and Build.   The version is in the pList, but not the build number, besides changing it there is a hack.

Anyone know where I can cleanly update the Extension Version/Build?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apple deleted the simple, convenient way to change the build and version for extensions. Now, for the extension you have to go to the Target and change it under Build Settings / Versioning

Since the App and the Extension are always supposed to have the same Version/Build why can not that just be the easy default, with a wonky path to changing from default where required?

Comment: This has to be a bug. Please file a report.

Comment: It’s no bug, it’s clearly a design decision to obscure the path to a non-optional parameter setting. It doesn’t meet the definition of a bug, but it sure breaks my Dev experience.

Comment: I don't get why this decision has been made? Just got this as a warning: `The CFBundleShortVersionString of an app extension ('3.0') must match that of its containing parent app ('3.1').` But from my experience nothing seems to break if you don't set the same version. Not sure if it did in the past...

Answer (score 2):

Here is one workaround: The project (top level) settings also contains the Versioning section. So I added my "Current Project Version" (= "Version") and "Marketing Version" (= "Build") values there, and then deleted the same entries from all targets (which then automatically adopt the same value that was set at the project level, by inheritance).

This allows the app to build successfully without any version warnings, and only needs to be updated in one place.

The main drawback is that you have to remember in future again to update the versioning in the Project settings and can't use the General tab of a target without causing it to adopt versioning that needs to be independently updated again in future for that target.

Comment: Sadly, about as much work as the workflow going into Target/Build Settings/Versioning -  Apple took a straightforward, top level visible frequently used setting and buried it.

Comment: My App was working perfectly fine, but got this error when tried the solution you suggested


Unable to install "appName"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
Recovery Suggestion: Please check your project settings and ensure that a valid product has been built.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-11-01 06:51:40 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}

Comment: @Anand What do you see when you look at all the versioning keys now? That error message doesn't sound like something you'd get by modifying app version keys alone in the way I described.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid changing the version and build of each target every time:

1. Set the version and build for the entire project at top.
   [image: screenshot_1]
2. Delete the version and build for each target.
   [image: screenshort_2]
3. Now all targets will automatically get their version and build from the project setting.
   [image: screenshort_3]

Next time, you will only need to change the version and build for the entire project in the top.

Comment: It seems to be the optimal solution, although it needs extra caution to never set verision directly in the targets as that gets unsynchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Xcode (I want to say new in 14) have changed the App Store submission workflow between Xcode and App Store Connect.

There is an option where the hosting service now tells you what version number it thinks is next. It also does some basic number collision detection.

The overall behavior means that you can keep building and submitting without changing the number, and each upload will likely not get rejected for having a version+build number that matches something already uploaded to your team's account.

I'm open to the possibility that Apple has extended some of the version magic to extensions.

Also, I think circa Xcode 12, I noticed that extension version checking to App Store had basically stopped. (I have this one reference project that has many extensions, I would frequently fail to sync all the extensions version numbers, so I've seen the error plenty of times).

I'm not sure if anything changed officially, but I can say that since WWDC, I recently re-read all the available extension documentation, and there is not mention of any version-matching changes.

Comment: Yes! One can now use auto-versioning, especially when using Xcode Cloud.
Like most indie developers, I see no reason to
use the cloud, so have been manually versioning
all along, including releasing 3 update versions with Xcode 14.3.1 with manually synching the App and extension each time.

So in 15, you can set the App version/build and then get the warning to update the extension.

After rooting around, in Build Settings, there is, several levels deep, the fields to update.

Comment: There is no version magic: I just tried updating the version number of my main app and left the app extension as is, and got a build warning. I encourage everyone who finds this annoying to file a bug report to Apple. I just did so myself. Please bring the Identity tab for app extensions back so we can quickly update the build number and version string without having to look for them in the build settings.